# Almost all the hunks are failing while patching a diff taken from the old working copy

Tags: svn

I had saved my old working code in a diff and was working on another feature.
After doing >svn up, I tried to patch the same old working diff.

Almost all the hunks are failed and moved to .rej files.
Is there any easy way to deal with it or I need to code everything again?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to update your working copy to the revision it was at when you generated the diff / patch. Then apply the patch to your working copy.

Your collaborators could've committed changes to the same parts of your code, so the patch does not apply to HEAD revision.